# How to undo a ParseUser.setPassword() call?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am letting the user change his credentials.
He types new username, email and password and I go like:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
user.setUsername("MY NEW NAME");
user.setEmail(email);
user.setPassword("MY NEW PW");
user.saveInBackground(...);
```

So what? So this `save()` call might fail, for a big number of reasons (example: username already taken by someone else). I can tell that in this case **none of the above fields** gets updated, which is fair: I show an error, user knows that all went wrong.

Things get complicated if you notice that, even after the `ParseException`, the `user` above keeps its dirty fields, which couldn't be saved to the server. I.e.

```
//saveInBackground fails
//...
user.getUsername().equals("MY NEW NAME") // true!
```

### Issue

Now, I am able to get these fields back to the right values by calling `user.fetch()`, but this doesn't work with the `password` field.

This is particularly unwanted, because any future call to `save()` or such (which might not fail because maybe it's a completely different call) will update the password too! I.e.

```
//later
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
user.put("stuff");
user.save();
```

This won't only put "stuff", but **also change the password to "MY NEW PW"**.. without the user ever knowing.

Is there any way to reset the local `password` field, other than `fetch()` which doesn't work? I know I could save username, email and password with three different queries but that is not a possible solution for my case.

Comment: Try this:
“Undo” doesn't work for android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo
setOnItemClickListener doesn't work for me. Is this because I use in my adapter OnLongClickListener and setOnCheckedChangeListener?

Comment: ```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseUser oriUser = user.fetch(); // return a ParseUser instance, it's you want ?
oriUser.setPassword.equals(""MY NEW PW""); // true or false ?
```

Comment: But I don't think it is a good  way, fetch() will add once net access, the right way is bak in local by yourself before update values

Comment: @aWang I didn't test using `ParseUser user2 = user.fetch()`, I was calling `user.fetch()` alone and then quering `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()`. And this is the most frequent scenario, because later in the app I will need to call `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().save()`. I want `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` to be brought back to previous password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the newest release I've read in the changelog:

> V1.10.2 — SEPTEMBER 15, 2015
>
> New: Added ParseObject.revert() and revert(key) to allow reverting
>   dirty changes

Looks like this could be it. It was definitely needed.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround **could** be to use

```
+ becomeInBackground:
```

on PFUser class (with PFUser.currentUser().sessionToken as token) when save fails, but that is still a risk for becomeInBackground to fail.
It could at least prevent some cases to happend **if** becomeInBackground effectively undoes setPassword, and accepts current sessionToken as parameter, I haven't tested that

Answer (score 0):

If it was my problem I would try to create an oldUser first and save all current data to it, then when failing, it would be time to change every thing back to normal value, or if success it is time to kill oldUser. Hope it may help.

Comment: I was hoping into something provided by the framework, but if there isn't, this might a good workaround.. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

The password plain text is not stored in Parse and as such it cannot be obtained by your app. Found it here https://www.parse.com/questions/get-current-users-password-to-compare-it-with-a-string

If you want to change password you can use `ParseUser.requestPasswordResetInBackground()` so you will change the password with the help of email.

But if you need to get password really hard, you can store it in the `SharedPreferences` after the login.

Answer (score 0):

After some test and check, here are some conclusion.

1. In parse, "password" is a **special** field, you cannot access it by ParseUser, That is way ParseUser have setPassword() but haven't getPassword() method
2. Even in back-stage management [Core] - [Data] - [User], you can see "password" field is **Hidden**
3. That is why fetch() method cannot recover original "password" value

So, I think if want implements above you need, try this way

```
// First time register //
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
user.setUsername("MY NAME");
user.setEmail(email);
user.setPassword("MY PW");
user.put("_password", "MY PW");
// The key can't use "password", this's reserve key word in Parse //
user.saveInBackground(...);

// Next time update //
user.setUsername("MY NEW NAME");
user.setPassword("MY NEW PW");
user.saveInBackground(...);

// if have something exception //
user.fetch();
// user.setPassword(user.get("_password"));
user.save();
ParseUser.login("MY NAME", "MY PW"); // Error
ParseUser.login("MY NAME", "MY NEW PW"); // Ok

user.fetch();
user.setPassword(user.get("_password"));
user.save();
ParseUser.login("MY NAME", "MY PW"); // OK
```